How to reduce delay in service to service communication to handle Authentication and authorization in microservices architecture using flask
I have some questions about how to use authentication and authorization in microservices architecture using flask.
In detail, I have a microservice architecture where authentication is handled by a dedicated auth microservice, which also acts as an Identity Provider (IDP). The auth service manages role-based access control (RBAC), and other microservices need to authenticate and retrieve username and role details to control route access. I'm using token-based authentication and have implemented token revocation by customizing the jwt_required decorator (to verify the identity in the token) for each protected route.
In my current setup:
Each request from any microservices involves fetching the group/role information from the auth microservice, which I’ve cached to improve performance.
I also check if the token is in a blocklist (to handle revocation), but I’m not caching this step for security reasons.
The issue I’m facing is that checking the blocklist causes delays. My questions are:

Is this the correct strategy for handling token revocation and role-based access in a microservice environment?

If not, what is the best approach?

If this is a valid approach, how can I further optimize and reduce the delay caused by checking the blocklist.


